# Elasticsearch how to quickly find the result when search array fields

Tags: sql, json, elasticsearch

My JSON data:

```
{
  "date": 1484219926,
  "uid": "1234567",
  "interest": [
    "2000001",
    "2000002",
    "....",
    "2000xxx"
  ],
  "other": "xxxx"
}
```

The search result as the following SQL:

```
select count(*) 
from xxxxx 
where date > time1 and 
      date < time2 and 
      interest="20000xxx"
```

The filed interest may have 500 itmes. I want to quickly get the search result, what shou I do? The total data may be 2 billion.

Comment: what you tried already? is it slow already? did you do any measures?

Comment: yes, I tried, it will cost 4-5 seconds, then return the result. I want  it cost 1-2s.   I use the nginx and write DSL for searching, then return the result to users.